# Android In-App purchases. Can I retrieve the Title And Description?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I'm having a little trouble with in app purchases.  My app downloads a JSON file to get the skus of available products.  That way I don't have to update my code when I add a new product.  So when the user makes a purchase, it sends that sku to Google Play. That works.  The question is, how can I retrieve the product information from Google Play to show the user the title and description of the products?  I know you can export a CSV from Google play, but you have to be logged in to do that.  surely there is a better way.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’ll need to store the product information (such as name, description, etc.) on your own, either within your app or on an external server.

Answer (score 2):

Since end of 2012 Android supports the in app billing version 3.
Using this, you can simply run `getSkuDetails` with one or multiple SKU (your identifiers) and it will return you for example the price, title and description.

Comment: How long does it usually take for the price / description change made in the Google Play Developer console to take effect and propagate to devices?   I have a couple of products where I am testing a price and description change.   Using getSkuDetails(), The description change showed up fairly quickly.  However, it's been 2 hours and the price change has yet to appear - it's still getting the original price.   Also, what happens in this interim?  The price has changed for purchases, but the value shown to customers in the app will reflect the original price.